# 98 trailing zeroes for $a^ab^b$ find $\min{ab}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find the minimum of $ab$ if $a^a\cdot b^b$ has exactly 98 trailing zeroes.

We see that $a^a\cdot b^b=2^{98}\cdot 5^{98}\cdot k$ for odd integral k. Then $a^a=2^{pa}5^{qa}\cdots$ and $b^b=2^{rb}5^{sb}\cdots$. Thus $pa+rb=98=sb+qa$. Usually $a\cdot b$ is minimized when $a=b$, but there is no constraints that I could create. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to get intuition if we change 98 to, say, 3 trailing zeros? Then 
$$p 2^p 5^q k_1 + r 2^r 5^s k_2 = 3 = s 2^r 5^s k_2 + q 2^p 5^q k_1,$$
where $k_1 k_2 = k$, has fewer solutions to try.

Comment: @Baker5680 Your statement of "$a^a*b^b=2^{98}*5^{98}*k$ for odd integral k" is not quite accurate. Having exactly $98$ trailing $0$'s means that $a^a \times b^b = 2^{c} \times 5^{d} \times k$ where $\min(c,d) = 98$ and $\gcd(k,10) = 1$. Note you can potentially have more than $98$ factors of $5$ or of $2$, but not of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For positive integers $p,n$, let $\nu_p(n)$ represent the largest integer $k$ such that $p^k\mid n$. So we're looking for $a,b$ such that $\nu_{10}(a^ab^b)=98$.  As John Omielan notes in the comments, that means that we need one of $\nu_2(a^ab^b)$ and $\nu_5(a^ab^b)$ to be equal to $98$ and the other one equal to or greater than it.

A sufficiently motivated reader can quickly verify that $\nu_p(ab)=\nu_p(a)+\nu_p(b)$ if $a$ and $b$ are non-zero and that $\nu_p(a^n)=n\nu_p(a)$.

Let us consider $\nu_5(a^a)$.  This is $0$ if $5\not\mid a$.  On the other hand, if $5\mid a$, then $\nu_5(a^a)=a\nu_5(a)$ must also be a multiple of $5$. Thus, $\nu_5(a^a)$ is always a multiple of 5, and there are therefore no solutions to $\nu_5(a^ab^b)=\nu_5(a^a)+\nu_5(b^b)=98$.

So we will need an exact solution to $\nu_2(a^ab^b)=98$.  This is at least possible.  In fact, $\nu_2(98^{98})=98\nu_2(98)=98$, since $98=2\cdot49$.  So one batch of solutions to our problem would be $a=98$ and $b$ a sufficiently large odd multiple of 5 that $\nu_5(b^b)\ge98$.  (These $b$ would be $75, 105, 115, 125, ....$)

Is there a solution where both $a$ and $b$ are even?  At least one of those numbers would need to be divisible by $10$, but they could not both be (as then $\nu_2(a^ab^b)$ would also a multiple of 10 instead of $98$). The only possibility that would contribute enough powers of $5$ without too many powers of $2$ is if $b=50$.  $\nu_5(50^{50})=50\cdot2=100$ and $\nu_2(50^{50})=50\cdot1=50$, so we'd be set if there were an $a$ such that $\nu_2(a^a)=48$.  But there is no such $a$: for instance $\nu_2(12^{12})=12\cdot2=24$ and $\nu_2(24^{24})=24\cdot3=72$.

Therefore, our optimal solution is $75^{75}98^{98}$, so $ab=7350$.